# WooCommerce tabs underneath each other

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm looking for a way to put the WooCommerce tabs and the content underneath each other in blocks. I've added an image with the example. Can anyone help me out?

[image: wc tabs example]

Answer (score 1):

Try this PHP snippet – it will remove the tabs and the call each of the template parts to display them in a stack. The below code works for Description and Additional Info tabs and you might have to modify it slightly to include all your tabs.

Paste the below code in `functions.php` or use the [Code Snippets Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) to add the below code:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme','db_stack_product_tabs' );

function db_stack_product_tabs(){ 
    // Remove product tabs
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 ); 
    // Get tab content template parts
    add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary','db_get_tab_template_parts', 10 );
}

function db_get_tab_template_parts() {
    // Include required template parts
    ?>
    <div class="woo-description-section"><?php wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' ); ?></div>
    <div class="woo-information-section"><?php wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' ); ?></div>
    <?php comments_template();
}
```

Comment: I used this code and worked, the issue is that it is visible also on products with empty  description and/or additional information, how can we hide them when empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_description_tab' ) ) {

    /**
     * Output the description tab content.
     */
    function woocommerce_product_description_tab() {
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' );
    }
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab' ) ) {

    /**
     * Output the attributes tab content.
     */
    function woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab() {
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/additional-information.php' );
    }
}
```

This is how those blocks are rendered.

Please copy single-product/tabs/description.php into your active theme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php

and single-product/tabs/additional-information.php to your active theme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/additional-information.php

Modify according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

With Storefront theme, I just use the following CSS to achive full-width, horizontal tabs:

```
/* TABS ************************* */
.woocommerce-tabs .panel h2:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 1.8823529412%;
    }
    .woocommerce-tabs .panel {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: or you could try this plugin:
WooCommerce Expand Tabs

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve by the custom hooks provided by woocommerce you can follow below [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/)

you can use below function in your `functions.php` to change the structure of the tab

```
/**
 * Customize product data tabs
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_description_tab', 98 );
function woo_custom_description_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['description']['callback'] = 'woo_custom_description_tab_content';    // Custom description callback

    return $tabs;
}

function woo_custom_description_tab_content() {
    echo '<h2>Custom Description</h2>';
    echo '<p>Here\'s a custom description</p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not looking for a way to add a new custom tab. I want to put all existing tabs underneath each other.

Comment: function is not adding the new tab its changing the content of the description tab

Comment: I'm not looking to change the content either. I want my existing tabs to be shown serarately and underneath eachother as shown in the image of my post.

Comment: then you have to make changes in template files directly also you have to fetch the content accordingly for each div

Comment: Does not answer the question